# Cache page with ajax loaded content

Tags: jquery, ajax, caching

I have some page with `$.ajax (POST)` script which loads the images (gallery page). I.e. first loads blank page only with header info, and then ajax loads the main content. Also, when user scrolls down, ajax function loads next portion of content.

When i click on some image it opens in a new page (viewer page). I use "back" button on browser to return to gallery page. But when i do it, gallery starts to load again from first image (first portion of images).

So question is: how to cache page with ajax-loaded content to make possible turn back to it without reloading and on saved position.

Comment: you need to open the image on the same page, with fancypopup or something like that.

Comment: @VolkanUlukut answered 4 years ago. you serious?

Comment: well you think you are the first guy who encountered this kind of a problem?

Comment: @VolkanUlukut no, i need to open image on other page, cuz except image it contains comments, likes, and some other info

Comment: @VolkanUlukut no, i just think here must be much newer solution

Comment: if you navigate away from a page, the state of that page is lost. forever. so what you need to do to workaround that problem is to stay on the same page. that doesn't mean you can't show comments/likes/other info on the same page. you just need to use javascript and ajax properly.

Comment: the easiest way i can think of is to hide the gallery and load the data of the image viewer page in a new div and show that instead. and once the user clicks back button, you could just make the gallery visible and remove the image div. so the state of the gallery always stays the same.

Comment: oh and also if you don't provide your own code, what you did and what went wrong, noone can help you.

Comment: @VolkanUlukut yes, i already think about this way to solve my problem, but i dont wish to overload my pages.

Comment: @VolkanUlukut I voted for your comment - it the best solution, i think. Thank you.